# How do i change the inner html of paragraph using jquery while using dynamic id in razor view of asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I was trying to change the inner html of one paragraph which is in the for loop of razor view. As my quantity changes the Total price should change. Here is my razor view with dynamic id given.

```
<section id="cart_items">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive cart_info">

            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="cart_menu">
                        <td class="image">Item</td>
                        <td class="description"></td>
                        <td class="price">Price</td>
                        <td class="quantity">Quantity</td>
                        <td class="total">Total</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr id="@item.CartID">
                            <td class="cart_product">
                                <a href=""><img src="@Url.Content(item.Product.ProductImage)" style="width:40px;height:40px" alt="" /></a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_description">
                                <h4><a href="">@item.Product.ProductName</a></h4>
                                <p>Web ID: 1089772</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_price">
                                <p class="cartprice" id="price">@item.Product.Price</p>
                                <input hidden id="abc" type="text" value="1" />
                            </td>
                            <td id="@item.Product.Price" class="cart_quantity">
                                <div class="cart_quantity_button">
                                    <a class="cart_quantity_up" id="AddButton"> + </a>
                                    <input class="cart_quantity_input" id="TextBox" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" autocomplete="off" size="2">
                                    <a class="cart_quantity_down" id="subbutton"> - </a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_total">
                                <p id="totprice" class="cart_total_price">@item.Product.Price</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_delete">
                             @*   <a class="cart_quantity_delete" href="@Url.Action("RemoveCart", "Home",new {id=item.CartID})"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>*@
                                <p id="cart" hidden>@item.CartID</p>
                                <a id="Remove" class="cart_quantity_delete" href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!--/#cart_items-->
<section id="do_action">
</section>
```

I have used jquery to change the quantity dynamically when click on plus symbol and decraese when click on minus symbol having given some id to it.

This is my jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.cart_quantity_up').click(function(){
            var quantityBox = $("#TextBox", $(this).parent());
            var currentValue = quantityBox.val();
            var w = parseInt($(this).closest('td').prop('id'));
            quantityBox.val(parseInt(currentValue) + 1);
            var oldprice = $("#price").html();
            var totprice = parseInt(w) * quantityBox.val();
            $('#' + w).find("#totprice").text(totprice);
        });

        $('.cart_quantity_down').click(function() {
            var quantityBox = $("#TextBox", $(this).parent());
            var currentValue = quantityBox.val();
            quantityBox.val(parseInt(currentValue) - 1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to make the changes in total price of the item where I incresed the quantity. Here is what i tried but not able to change the proper value. So how can i do it. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are trying to access the `$("#price").html()` which scans the whole document and because you have wrote the loop their are multiple element with the same id `#price' so it is not able to decide which one to pick.

The code which you have wrote it is more complicated to what you are trying to achieve.

Try the following code in place of your.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.cart_quantity_up').click(function(){
            var quantityBox = $(this).siblings("#TextBox");
            var quantity= parseInt(quantityBox.val()) + 1;
            quantityBox.val(quantity);

            var price = parseInt($(this).parent().siblings(".cart_price").children("#price").html());
            var totalPrice = quantity * price;
            $(this).parent().siblings(".cart_total").children("#totprice").html(totalPrice);
        });

        $('.cart_quantity_down').click(function() {
            var quantityBox = $(this).siblings("#TextBox");
            var quantity= parseInt(quantityBox.val()) - 1;
            quantityBox.val(quantity);

            var price = parseInt($(this).parent().siblings(".cart_price").children("#price").html());
            var totalPrice = quantity * price;
            $(this).parent().siblings(".cart_total").children("#totprice").html(totalPrice);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Praddyumna-Sangvikar please update the `var price = parseInt` to `var price = parseFloat` because product price can be in decimals.