# As I change the quantity of the product the total bill should change by adding all the prices and display it on same page. How can I do it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

As I change the quantity of some items the total bill should change respectively. How can I make addition of all the product prices to generate total bill. The following is my code of cart.cshtml file.

```
<section id="cart_items">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive cart_info">
      <table class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr class="cart_menu">
            <td class="image">Item</td>
            <td class="description"></td>
            <td class="price">Price</td>
            <td class="quantity">Quantity</td>
            <td class="total">Total</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
          <tr id="@item.CartID">
            <td class="cart_product">
              <a href=""><img src="@Url.Content(item.Product.ProductImage)" style="width:40px;height:40px" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td class="cart_description">
              <h4><a href="">@item.Product.ProductName</a></h4>
              <p>Web ID: 1089772</p>
            </td>
            <td class="cart_price">
              <p class="cartprice" id="price">@item.Product.Price</p>
              <input hidden id="abc" type="text" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td id="@item.Product.Price" class="cart_quantity">
              <div class="cart_quantity_button">
                <a class="cart_quantity_up" id="AddButton"> + </a>
                <input class="cart_quantity_input" id="TextBox" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" autocomplete="off" size="2">
                <a class="cart_quantity_down" id="subbutton"> - </a>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="cart_total">
              <p id="totprice" class="cart_total_price">@item.Product.Price</p>
            </td>
            <td class="cart_delete">
              @*   <a class="cart_quantity_delete" href="@Url.Action("RemoveCart", "Home",new {id=item.CartID})"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>*@
              <p id="cart" hidden>@item.CartID</p>
              <a id="Remove" class="cart_quantity_delete" href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="do_action">
  <div class="container text-right">
    <h2 id="totalbill">Total Bill: <span> </span></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container text-center">
     @* <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default check_out" href="@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")">Check Out</a>*@
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home"))
     {
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default check_out" value="Check Out" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Check out??');" />
     }
  </div>
</section>
```

User can increase the quantity as he wants. so the bill should also increases as he increases the quantity. I am confused how to do that. I want to make an addition of prices and make a total bill.
This is my jquery that I have used for increasing quantity and likewise changing the price of particular product.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cart_quantity_up').click(function () {
      var quantityBox = $("#TextBox", $(this).parent());
      var currentValue = quantityBox.val();
      var w = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').prop('id'));
      var x = parseInt($(this).closest('td').prop('id'));
      quantityBox.val(parseInt(currentValue) + 1);
      var totprice = parseInt(x) * quantityBox.val();
      $('#'+w).find("#totprice").text(parseInt(totprice));
    });

    $('.cart_quantity_down').click(function () {
      var quantityBox = $("#TextBox", $(this).parent());
      var currentValue = quantityBox.val();
      var w = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').prop('id'));
      var x = parseInt($(this).closest('td').prop('id'));
      quantityBox.val(parseInt(currentValue) - 1);
      // var totprice = parseInt(x) * quantityBox.val();//
      //$('#' + w).find("#totprice").text(parseInt(totprice));
    });
  });
</script>
```

So please help me to do addition of all the products prices and generate a total bill and display it on same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can all together replace your scripts with the following as i have rewrote it.

**Note:** i have changed the `parseInt` to `parseFloat` for product price because product has the price in floating value not in integer value.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.cart_quantity_up').click(function(){
            var quantityBox = $(this).siblings("#TextBox");
            var quantity= parseInt(quantityBox.val()) + 1;
            quantityBox.val(quantity);

            var price = parseFloat($(this).parent().siblings(".cart_price").children("#price").html());
            var totalPrice = quantity * price;
            $(this).parent().siblings(".cart_total").children("#totprice").html(totalPrice);

            updateBill();
        });

        $('.cart_quantity_down').click(function() {
            var quantityBox = $(this).siblings("#TextBox");
            var quantity= parseInt(quantityBox.val()) - 1;
            quantityBox.val(quantity);

            var price = parseFloat($(this).parent().siblings(".cart_price").children("#price").html());
            var totalPrice = quantity * price;
            $(this).parent().siblings(".cart_total").children("#totprice").html(totalPrice);

            updateBill();
        });
    });

    function updateBill(){
         var totalBill=0.0;
         $(".cart_total_price").each(function(){ 
              totalBill+=parseFloat($(this).html()) 
         })
         $("#totalbill > span").html(totalBill);
    }
</script>
```

I think this is almost same question as the [how-do-i-change-the-inner-html-of-paragraph-using-jquery-while-using-dynamic-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993177/how-do-i-change-the-inner-html-of-paragraph-using-jquery-while-using-dynamic-id/40995458#40995458) which i have answered except you additionally need to update the `Total Bill Amount`.

Comment: Really Thankful for your reply.. I have a small query. Here after clicks on the plus symbol the total bill is generating correctly but it is not changing the total of individual product. I have checked it. Its giving NAN value of Toatal price of individual item.

Comment: I want to change the total bill after user clicking on input  and typing in the quantity. So how can i make change in my code???